# Online LDAP Book like zytrax.com with new OLC (cn=config) configuration

Tags: ldap, openldap

Is there a good online book or blog post similar to the [zytrax ldap book](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap) where they use the new online config OLC (cn=config)?

I'm relative new to ldap and look for a good reference and quickstart. I want to configure OpenLDAP on an debian system for a sogo, exim, dovecot driven mail server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I would have been heard. Here is an excellent article about this: http://www.rjsystems.nl/en/2100-d6-openldap-provider.php